# Create a PDF file using LaTex templates and Java

Tags: java, templates, latex, pdf-generation

I need to create a report system using LaTex templates and Java like programming language. I use JLR library but it's freeeware, this is my code:

```
    File workingDirectory = new File("./config/output");
    File desktop = new File("./config/desktop");
    File invoice1 = new File("./config/templates/template1.tex");
    File invoice2 = new File("./config/templates/template2.tex");
    JLRGenerator pdfGen = new JLRGenerator();

    pdfGen.deleteTempTexFile(false);

    if (!pdfGen.generate(invoice1, desktop, workingDirectory)) { 
        System.out.println(pdfGen.getErrorMessage());
    }

    JLROpener.open(pdfGen.getPDF());

    if (!pdfGen.generate(invoice2, desktop, workingDirectory)) {
        System.out.println(pdfGen.getErrorMessage());
    }

    JLROpener.open(pdfGen.getPDF());
```

Searching into the Web I find JLatexMath but, as far as I know, only generates equations in LaTex and not the entire PDF. Do you know a library in Java which generates an entire PDF file using a LaTex template?

Update: I execute de .tex file using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pdflatex.exe...") command. But I don't achive save the PDF file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. You've stated a need and then asked if a solution exists. Of course, a solution exists! You want other people to do your work for you. Please show your work, or ask a more specific, technical question.

Comment: Thank you Bob and I'm sorry for my question, I don't want to anyone do my job. I'll try to explain myself better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have the solution, here is the code:

```
public void generateReport()
{
Process p;
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode ./config/log/document.tex");
    p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

It generates a .PDF and .dvi file in the same place of your .tex file. Thank you much for your help :)